# How to download a GitHub repo as .zip using command line

Tags: command-line, wget, zip, github

I am trying to download a .zip file from GitHub using the command line in Ubuntu. I am using `wget` command for it on a remote Ubuntu system.

I run `wget <link>` where `<link>` is the address bar link of the file which I want to download. It ends with `archive.zip?ref=master`.

Now, when I am executing the command, it is downloading a file with `text/html` type and not the `.zip` file which I want.

Please tell me how to get the link to be given as the parameter of `wget`. Right now, I am just copying the link address of the button (using right click) and writing that as a `wget` parameter.

Comment: can you tell the exact command you are pasting?

Comment: Does your URL really ends with .zip?

Comment: @kashish No the URL does not end with .zip . I am trying to download a project from github and it has a download button giving zip and other options. So, I'm trying from there. it ends with archive.zip?ref=master

Comment: To download a github project, you can use `git clone <projectlink.git>`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it possible to download a repository as Zip-file using a following address: `https://github.com/{user}/{repo}/archive/{branch}.zip`

Comment: @AlexChermenin that's true but only opening it in a browser and not using wget (see my answer)

Comment: @derHugo what's the difference between using wget + url and opening the url in a browser?

Comment: I assume you did not read my answer here below... on a browser you may be redirected/forwarded to another URL .. with wget this will not happen but you will get whatever file the URL points to

Comment: @derHugo It's ok when wget received a response `302` and continue downloading with new address. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74338

Comment: Because in this case with sourceforge you were redirected instantly. Github redirects you after buiding the zip file. wget doesn't whait if there's a redirect later or not it just downloads the actual file.

Comment: @derHugo Did you try? I tried with several different repositories and branches and every time i receive the right result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: yes and all I get is: `Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.253.112, 192.30.253.113
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.253.112|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-07-27 14:40:20 ERROR 404: Not Found.` additional wget doesn't know your credentials so you would have to provide them as text which just isn't good

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the comments I saw you actually speak about GitHub.

It won't work like this because:

Downloading a project on GitHub causes the GitHub server to first pack your project as zip and than **forwarding** you to a **temporary** link where you get your zip ..

this link will only work for a certain time and than GitHub will delete your zip file from their servers..

So what you get with wget is just the html page which would forward you as soon as your zip file is generated.

As suggested use

```
git clone http://github.com/<yourRepoLink> <optional local path where to store>
```

to download the git repo ... If for some reason (e.g. for transfer it to others) you need it explicitly as zip you still could pack it after cloning is finished..

Comment: After cloning, do `git archive -o output.zip`, if a zip file is still needed

Comment: `git clone` works, naturally, but there are cases when it doesn't make sense to install git just to download a repo.

Answer (score 22):

It **does** work, if you use the correct URL.

For a GitHub repo, there's a zip at `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/archive/<branch>.zip`, so you can download it with:

```bash
wget https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/archive/<branch>.zip
```

This downloads the zipped repo for a given branch. Note that you can also replace the branch by a commit hash.

#### Using cURL

```bash
curl -L -O https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/archive/<branch>.zip
```

cURL's `-L` flag follows redirects - it's a default in wget. `-O` is advised by Phil Gibbins in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939830/how-to-download-a-github-repo-as-zip-using-command-line/1236771#comment2125069_1236771).

#### Download a .tgz instead of .zip

You can also download a tarball with:

```bash
wget https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/archive/<branch>.tar.gz
```

Comment: **`curl -L -O <url>` works on MacOS**; (posting because it's all Unix related) thanks for adding the information about `curl`; I landed here when searching for the equivalent on MacOS, and albeit not hard to install it, `wget` isn't installed by default (my use case limits me from installing). You're advised to add `-O` as "Binary output can mess up your terminal"

Answer (score 1):

## 2021 Update Download and unzip from GitHub Using wget

**Will also expand and delete the archive. Just edit the REPLACE_ values and then copy/paste**

### zip

```
GH_USER=REPLACE_WITH_USER \
GH_REPO=REPLACE_WITH_REPO \
GH_BRANCH=REPLACE_WITH_BRANCH \
wget https://github.com/${GH_USER}/${GH_REPO}/archive/refs/tags/${GH_BRANCH}.zip \
-O "${GH_REPO}-${GH_BRANCH}.zip" && \ 
unzip ./"${GH_REPO}-${GH_BRANCH}.zip" && \
rm ./"${GH_REPO}-${GH_BRANCH}.zip"
```

### tgz

```
GH_USER=REPLACE_WITH_USER \
GH_REPO=REPLACE_WITH_REPO \
GH_BRANCH=REPLACE_WITH_BRANCH \
wget https://github.com/${GH_USER}/${GH_REPO}/archive/refs/tags/${GH_BRANCH}.tar.gz \
-O "${GH_REPO}-${GH_BRANCH}.tar.gz" && \
tar -xzvf ./"${GH_REPO}-${GH_BRANCH}.tar.gz" && \
rm ./"${GH_REPO}-${GH_BRANCH}.tar.gz"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did it, but make sure you're using the correct link with URL end with `*.zip` like what [@Robin Métral](https://askubuntu.com/a/1236771/1339337) said above.

The exact steps I did:

1. Open GitHub repository.
2. Right click the ***Download Zip*** link, and copy the URL.
3. Use that copied URL with `wget` in terminal.

I believe GitHub server will accept `wget` request and treat it as same as request with browser.