# Install Github Software as a repo?

Tags: software-installation, repository, software-sources, github

I read this: [How to download a GitHub repo as .zip using command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939830/how-to-download-a-github-repo-as-zip-using-command-line) but I'm still unclear about it.

Is there or is there not a way to add github or a github project, as a repo to Ubuntu 18.04, so that when I install a program, say [freetube](https://github.com/FreeTubeApp/FreeTube) for example, from that repo, it will stay up to date.

Comment: Well, technically there is a way, but github repository has to have debian package ( debian folder ), and then you'd have to create a PPA and import that github repository into PPA. This means you'd have to communicate with developer/maintainer of the said repository and request them to make a debian directory and get permission to create the package ( be mindful of the license )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: No, you can't.

`git` repos and Ubuntu repos are quite different.

`git` repos in most cases contain software sources that need compilation.

Ubuntu repos contain `deb` binaries that can be directly installed to Ubuntu.

There are some exceptions. `git` can contain binary files and some `deb` packages can contain sources that are compiled by Ubuntu, e.g. DMKS ones.

But still they are very different and there is no general way to "install a git repo as an Ubuntu repo".

Generally speaking, you'll need to do `git pull` on a `git` repo to update the sources and then compile the program each time you want to update unless you create a script that will do it for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility, if you wanted to go down this route, is to look into making a snap package. I know that snap packages are able to be built automatically when using a webhook for a github repository. This may be more work then you are looking to do, but it is an option that, if published, the entire community could benefit from

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: This is interesting. I'm not sure how to do this but I might take a look at it. I prefer flatpaks though....